# Floating element breaks to new page while max-width present

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to understand how to make my layout responsive. I have the following code:

```
<style>
  .wrapper{width:1000px;}
  .left{float:left; width:100%;max-width:641px;display:inline;}
  .right{float:left;width:359px;display:inline;}
</style>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Now this is OK while the window width is over 1000px. When I shrink the window, the div.right is pushed to the new line instead of giving me the resposive shrinking of div.left. Please point me to the right direction. Thanx!

Comment: What you claim is not true - http://jsfiddle.net/easwee/9d4ZR/

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct code because this does not happen with this code. It cant because both divs fit in the parents fixed width.

Comment: easwee, I need the div.left to shrink when I shrink the window. As you may perfectly see, this is not happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You sound like you want something flex-box can solve easily. http://codepen.io/tkrugg/pen/pmhrE
If you support only recent browsers, you should give it a try.

```
  .wrapper{  
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
            flex-direction: row;
    max-width:1000px;
  }
  .left{
    flex-grow:1;
  }
  .right{    
    flex-basis:359px; 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

add this Style to your html. this will work fine.

[Demo](http://cdpn.io/cDsrH)

```
.wrapper{
  display:table;
  max-width:1000px; 
  width:100%; 
}
  .left{
    display:table-cell;
    max-width:641px;
  }
  .right{
    display:table-cell;
    width:349px;
  }
```

Comment: I believe he tried to keep the right div at a fixed width, while scaling the left one.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're doing it wrong. What you should do instead is to use `display: table;` CSS property. That's how fluid grids work. So your code becomes this:

```
<style>
    .wrapper { max-width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto; }
    .row { display: table; width: 100%; height: auto; }
    .left { /* 641px / 1000px = 0.641 * 100 = 64.1% */
        width: 64.1%; display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; }
    .right { /* 359px / 1000px = 0.359 * 100 = 35.9% */
        width: 35.9%; display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; }
</style>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You would have to create a breakpoint for mobile, and stack your divs on top of each other simply by setting `display: block;` and `width: 100%;`.

Answer (score -1):

your code has some errors.only left div can see. if my answer doesn't help please put your whole code so people can see the error easily.

how ever your requirement can be achieved adding.

```
position: absolute;
```

to the right div like below.

```
.right{float:left;width:359px;display:inline;position: absolute;}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Because your answer is wrong. if you put position absolute that will overlap to other one. (i didn't down vote)

Comment: @JeyTheva I tested it and i couldn't find that kind of a problem. how ever if i delete my answer now, will they restore my reputation points back?

Comment: I think you can't get back your reputation. But I'm not sure.

Comment: aioo. so sad. i should not answer if i'am not sure.